# Can Unreal Engine Blueprints do everything C ++ code can?

Tags: c++, unreal-4, blueprints

Can Unreal Engine Blueprints do everything that C++ code can?

Or are there limitations and some stuff you can't do in Blueprint and only using C++?

Answer (score 8):

No.

C++ functionality in the Unreal engine is exposed to Blueprints explicitly, using macros in the C++ source code to identify functions and types that are Blueprint-accessible. Using that mechanism, the native aspects of the engine are exposed directly or exposed via ease-of-use wrappers to Blueprint.

Therefore there are portions of the Unreal Engine that aren't accessible to a Blueprint which may be accessible to C++ code.

This may or may not be a practical problem depending on what you actually need to do. Low-level rendering and physics APIs aren't directly exposed to Blueprint, for example. If you need to twiddle around in the guts of the engine's functionality via those APIs, you'll want to drop down to C++, either in your game code or even by modifying the engine code directly.

But if you're mainly concerned about higher-level gameplay logic and flow, you can almost certainly do everything you'd want via Blueprints.